# Is it OK to automate Git commands?

Tags: git, bash

I'm coming from FTP, where if I wanted to edit some text quickly, I could just upload the file and see the change. I know I need to use Git, so I have automated the 3 step process (add, commit, push) using Bash shell programming.  Is this OK to do?

```
// in .bashrc file
launch() { 
  git add -A . ;
  git commit -m "$1" ;
  git push heroku master ;
  echo $1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely OK.

It's totally normal to automate SCM commands, and in fact happens often with Continuous Integration.

Just be wary.  you are using the "-A" flag, so if you have a file that you don't want, and isn't ignored, will be added to the commit.

Exercise vigilance, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I use .gitignore to ignore files I don't need.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, it's fine. There is just one error to fix:

```
launch () {
    git add -A .
    git commit -m "$1"
    git push heroku master
    echo "$1"
}
```

Without the quotes, a use like

```
launch "my commit message"
```

would produce an error, as only "my" would be used as the argument to `-m`, with "commit" and "message" appearing as separate arguments to the `commit` command. The semicolons are simply unnecessary, but wouldn't cause any harm if kept.

Comment: Not really; a newline is just one of the valid statement terminators. Semicolons are only used to terminate a command that is followed by another on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is okay,  but you could end up with a long history of small edits without any comments on them.  Although I do see you have included -m option for your commits.

One way you could use this workflow and have a sane history is to keep your live code in a separate branch.  And periodically do interactive rebase squashing series of small commits into fewer larger commits that are semantically close.

Then you can put these larger commits into your master branch.